# Browser opens instead of console application when debugging

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, debugging

I am writing a WCF service and a simple console-application to test it. When I select my test-project (console application) in solution explorer and press F5 the project builds and opens a browser window instead of my console app. But I can find my console app in Debug folder and launch it manually. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Do you set option 'Set as startup project' for your console app?

Comment: @Alexander, thank you, that was the problem. Make it an answer so that I choose it?

Comment: It wasn't really a constructive question!

Comment: @FaizanMubasher, yeah, I agree, but I could not understand the roots of the problems, and I could not google the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set option 'Set as startup project' for your console app (from context menu on your console project in Solution Explorer).